# how to put the word AND in a printf statement

Tags: java

I want to put the word "and "in the printf statement, how do I Do that in the following code? I have used a comma in the printf statement however i get an error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class faarh {
public static void main(String[] args ){
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.print("Enter a , b, and c : ");
double a = input.nextDouble();
double b = input.nextDouble();
double c = input.nextDouble();



//getting the discrminat
double discriminant = Math.pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c);

//the roots
double root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt (discriminant))/2 * a ;
double root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt (discriminant))/2 * a ;

if (discriminant > 0 ){
System.out.printf ("The roots are %8.4f%8.4f" , root1, "and ",  root2);
}
if (discriminant < 0){
System.out.println("There are no real roots ");
 }
if (discriminant == 0){
System.out.println("There roots are  " + root1);
 }

}
}
```

Comment: Just put it in the format string, "The roots are %8.4f and %8.4f". Why do you need it as an argument to the method?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
System.out.printf("The roots are %8.4f and %8.4f", root1, root2);
```

Read more about `printf` in [Java Docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Remember the declaration of the method `printf` is:

```
printf(String format, Object... args)
```

> The first parameter, `format`, is a format string specifying how the objects in the second parameter, `args`, are to be formatted. The format string contains plain text as well as **format specifiers**, which are special characters that format the arguments of `Object... args`. (The notation `Object... args` is called varargs, which means that the number of arguments may vary.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```
System.out.printf ("The roots are %8.4f and %8.4f" , root1, root2);
```

Or this...

```
System.out.printf ("The roots are %8.4f%s%8.4f" , root1, " and ",  root2);
```